# DSAS APP doesnt recognize my baseline shapefile says its not projected or the projection is not in meters

Tags: digital-shoreline-analysis-system

I have created a personal geodatabase which includes a baseline feature layer and a shoreline feature layer both in WGS84 coordinate system. [DSAS](https://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/DSAS/) casts transects in order to calculate shore erosion.

When I try to cast transects an error pops up saying:

```
Baseline layer is either not projected or the projection does not use metres as linear unit. Edit projection baseline
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need units of measure to be in metres then you'll need a projected not a geographic coordinate reference system; so if you currently have [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326) you'll need to reproject your data, as EPSG:4326 has units of degrees.